# I created .env file for my Api and when I fetch data it shows 'Request failed with status code 403' (Axios Error)

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app, strapi

Error Message

> AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 403', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const data = await axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/products", {
                    headers: { Authorization: "bearer" + process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKEN, }
                })
                console.log(data)

            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)

            }`your text`
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [])
```

in my .env file(it is inside root)
//I changed the version of axios but it didn't work

```
REACT_APP_API_TOKEN =d497def4a0c937df0c7ee1514a2975f3ab433df1557bda09405350247ff23425f1c47fabe1dbcb5433c89be91344f7557a2fe0060da7fa006570bf82ae7bb65c81f5aa469dbaaf1576ab8a28f4a65892653aebb394581423495c951c90e697d67fe1c5d08dfa10a6b834d3e06cdc37d54b837d1ec10aebabb9fb86d9adfb1600
REACT_APP_API_URL = http://localhost:1337/api
```

Comment: You are getting 403, which means your token is not valid. Generate a new token with correct permissions

Comment: I did but still same, this is my second api token, which I have posted

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure, but did you just forgot a space in the way you're setting you're Header here ? Shouldn't it be :

```js
headers: { Authorization: "bearer " + process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKEN, }
```